# Text Invertion Android

Tags: android, text, inversion

Anybody knows how to write upside down text of edit text in Android

thanks

/minhaz

Answer (score 0):

For that effect that looks sort of like this -> ıɥʇ ǝʞıl ɟo ʇɹos sʞool ʇɐɥʇ ʇɔǝɟɟǝ ʇɐɥʇ ɹoℲ

You would need to convert input characters into the appropriate upside-down looking Unicode characters.

You can find a character map here:

http://www.upsidedowntext.com/unicode

Answer (score 0):

in the xml file add

android:rotation="180"

in the respective element to display text upside down